# How to create a com object for a specific version of application using python comtypes.client?

Tags: python, com, canoe

I am trying to automate canoe application. I am trying to create a com object. But I have 2 different Canoe versions 7.6 and 8.2. By default it opens 7.6 version of Canoe. How do I make sure it opens 8.2 Version by default?

```
import comtypes.client
CANOE_COM_APPLICATION = "CANoe.Application"
app = comtypes.client.CreateObject(CANOE_COM_APPLICATION)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, this office article [Office automation when multiple versions of Office are installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/292491/office-automation-when-multiple-versions-of-office-are-installed) will be helpful.

- Multiple version of "Canoe" can be installed on one PC at the same time
- Each version of "Canoe" has an identifiable PROGID

If the above two conditions are satisfied, you can switch the target by specifying PROGID of the desired version number.

Comment: If I try to register "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vector CANoe 8.2\Exec32\CANoe32.exe" . It says registration failed.

Comment: Have you checked whether multiple versions can be installed? Next, use Registry Editor to search for "CANoe.Application" and check whether there is PROGID which can distinguish the version, such as "CANoe.Application.8". If you can not do them, please ask the developer about your request.

Comment: I can only see CANoe.Application.1 for which local server 32 has a path pointing out to Canoe 7.6V. If I change this to 8.2. My normal script works, but When I try to integrate into Jenkins, it still takes 7.6V. I am not sure why this is behaving differently.

Comment: Developers will not assume your usage. First of all, please ask the developer.